# What properties of this complex function can be deduced?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, complex-numbers, partial-derivative

Let $\Phi(x,y)$ be a complex function of $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ .

Given that $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \Phi^*(x,y) \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \Phi(x,y) \,dx$$

is purely imaginary:

- What properties of the complex function $\Phi(x,y)$ can be deduced?

Comment: What does $\Phi^*(x,y)$ mean? The complex conjugate?

Comment: Yep. Sry it was not explicit

Comment: When $\Phi$ is interpreted as a normalised 1D wavefunction in quantum mechanics, the integral is the expecation value of momentum, divided by $- i \hslash$, i.e. the imginary part of the integral is the mean momentum in plank units.

When you conclude $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}|\Phi|^2=\lim_{x\to\infty}|\Phi|^2,$$ this is to say that the probability density of the particle at extremes in space is equal, and for wavefunctions we set these to be zero.

Comment: @nathan.j.mcdougall It is while studying QM on my own that I had this particular doubt

Comment: Haha, makes sense.

Comment: I wanted to know what properties of the wavefunction can be deduced mathematically from the fact that the expectation value of momentum is not complex number. I even asked a question to that effect in Physics stack exchange but I was told no properties could be deduced. Then I wrote this question with some generality to it

Comment: Well you've shown there is a property: in particular that the probability density at extremes is equal. However, for normalised wavefunctions (note that in your general question here $\Phi$ needn't be normalised) this is true anyhow. So the physicists were correct, when speaking about wavefunctions, the fact that momentum is hermitian doens't give any more information about the wavefunction.

Generally, a proof that momentum is hermitian in the first place will require an integration by parts and then the evaluation of the boundary probability density, which zero by the normalisation.

Comment: @nathan.j.mcdougall Well, somebody could have told me that before and it would have answered both my question here and @ physics stack exchange.

Comment: @Lisa "This question has not received enough attention." How is that so?

Comment: @Did "Enough attention" is a bit subjective, I guess. Lisa felt so and offered a bounty.

Comment: @Truth-seek When, as here, answers have been posted, to declare that the "question has not received enough attention" is a rather blunt statement, which, sorry to say, happens to be wrong in the present case.

Comment: @Did In a way, I am responsible. [I asked a question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26507/what-to-do-when-i-get-no-feedback-on-an-answer-to-my-own-question). I just wanted to know whether my answer is correct, that's all. Lisa is trying to help me, I suppose.

Comment: @Truth-seek And why on Earth is Omno's answer not sufficient? The whole chain of events escapes me, I guess.

Comment: @Did Who said it is not sufficient? It is absolutely sufficient and is quite a well thought of, well placed hint. But, after a few days of thinking over this problem, I remembered that I had no idea whether the whole line of reasoning had been right. The answer is correct, but is the way I arrive at it wrong? That began the whole chain of events.

Comment: @Did Maybe the reason for all this is the fact that I am doing a lot of self-study nowadays. I am learning QM, multi-variable calculus, complex numbers and stuff on my own. So, every step I take forward, I must ensure every single step of reasoning is absolutely correct so that I do not fall into the trap of "false knowledge"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} |\Phi|^2 = 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (\Phi\Phi^*) = 
\Phi^*\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x} +  \Phi\frac{\partial \Phi^*}{\partial x} = 2 \operatorname{Re}\left[\Phi^*\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x} \right]
$$

Comment: how to use that?

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: I dont know if this is ryt. But I seemed to get: $$\lim_{x \to -\infty}|\Phi(x,y)|^{2}=\lim_{x \to \infty}|\Phi(x,y)|^{2}$$

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure that's what they're going for.

Comment: So that's ryt, ah?

Comment: I don't know what ryt means, but it seems right to me.

Comment: ryt means right, in case u weren't kidding

Answer (score 3):

Am not sure if this line of reasoning is correct. Omnomnomnom says that the answer I arrived at is correct [in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2294375/what-properties-of-this-complex-function-can-be-deduced#comment4721467_2294383). But, I wanted to make sure my reasoning is right. This is how I develepod on the hint provided by [Omnomnomnom's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2294383/425945):

If the integral of a complex function over some limits is purely imaginary, then the integral of the real part of the complex function over the same limits must be zero. Now, from the hint:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} |\Phi|^2 = 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (\Phi\Phi^*) = 
\Phi^*\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x} +  \Phi\frac{\partial \Phi^*}{\partial x} = 2 \operatorname{Re}\left[\Phi^*\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x} \right]
$$

So, putting all of this together, we get:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} |\Phi|^2 dx = 0
$$

Or:

$$
\lim_{x\to +\infty}|Φ(x,y)|^2 - \lim_{x\to −\infty}|Φ(x,y)|^2 = 0
$$

Further:

$$
\lim_{x\to +\infty}|Φ(x,y)|^2 = \lim_{x\to −\infty}|Φ(x,y)|^2
$$

Comment: Yes, that's the right line of reasoning.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thank you so much.